# How to use ajax for call php function in a function drag and drop javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have to do a project which can handle files system (upload a file, download, delete, rename, move a file in a folder etc etc...).
So i did a drag and drop for move a file in an other directory in javascript but i want in each transfer, call a php function for update the folder in my data base etc etc ... how can i do ? Here my drag and drop code :

```
window.onload = function () {
function drag_and_drop() {
    for (var items = document.querySelectorAll('[data-draggable="item"]'), len = items.length, i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        items[i].setAttribute('draggable', 'true');
    }

    /* DRAG N DROP */
    var item = null;

    document.addEventListener('dragstart', function (e) {
        item = e.target;
        e.dataTransfer.setData('text', '');

    }, false);
    document.addEventListener('dragover', function (e) {
        if (item) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }

    }, false);

    document.addEventListener('drop', function (e) {
        if (e.target.getAttribute('data-draggable') == 'target') {
            e.target.appendChild(item);
            e.preventDefault();
           /*call a php function here*/ 


        }

    }, false);

    document.addEventListener('dragend', function (e) {
        item = null;

    }, false);

}

drag_and_drop();
```

}

Comment: On every drop, you can trigger a AJAX call and send few things such as file name, dropped location to call. This call will hit your PHP endpoint where you can get these info. and update your db in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the jQuery Ajax Method to call a php file and give it parameters via POST.

An example for moving a file could look like this:

```
$.ajax({   
  type: "POST",   
  url: "/destination/to/php/file.php",   
  data: "sourceFile=" + sourcefile + "&destinationFile=" + destinationFile, 
  success: function(data) {
    // Request succeded, data is the string containing the result returned by the php file. This could be an error message or something else. You can also use JSON to have multiple values.
    // Decode json
    decodedData = JSON.decode(JSON.parse(data));
    if (decodedData == "success") {
      console.log("Moved file");
    } else {
      console.log("Error while moving file: " + decodedData);
    }
  },
  fail: function() {
    console.log("Request failed");
  }
});
```

Then in your PHP file you just read in the post values, do your action and return a message. I would recommend to decode/encode the message in JSON.

```
<?php
  $destinationFile = $_POST["sourceFile"];
  $sourceFile = $_POST["destinationFile"];
  // Change files in the Database

  if ($suceeded) {
    die(json_encode("succeded"));
  } else {
    die(json_encode($errormessage));
  }
```

If you want to have more than one PHP function in one file, just add a new parameter actionName or functionName or something and check in the php file with a "switch" which action/function you should execute.

Comment: i succeded to have my two variable in php, but why i have i do a console.log, i got my two variable and all my html ? :

Comment: This is just for debugging purpose. When the action executed successfully I would just update the UI. If it fails I would display something like an error alert. So you can replace the console.log with something that fits your needs.